# Why am i getting an exception when running Windows 8.1

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.winphone

I am developing an application in xamarin and android is running ok..but the following exception is raised whwn i run my Windows 8.1 project

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT.DLL but was not handled in user code

The exception comes from the following piece of code

```
public sealed partial class MainPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        LoadApplication(new MyApp.App());
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

> at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT.Platform.SetPage(Page newRoot) at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT.WindowsBasePage.LoadApplication‌​(Application application) at Marula.Windows.MainPage..ctor() at Marula.Windows.Marula_Windows_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvi‌​der.Activate_4_MainP‌​age() at Marula.Windows.Marula_Windows_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.Acti‌​vateInstance() InnerException:

Comment: What is null here?  Is it MyApp?  Drop a breakpoint on the LoadApplication() line and investigate.

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: StackTrace:
       at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT.Platform.SetPage(Page newRoot)
       at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT.WindowsBasePage.LoadApplication(Application application)
       at Marula.Windows.MainPage..ctor()
       at Marula.Windows.Marula_Windows_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_4_MainPage()
       at Marula.Windows.Marula_Windows_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
  InnerException: